# App run from Qt creator uses different library than when its run on its own

Tags: c++, macos, curl, qt-creator, dylib

I have to use sftp to upload files when application is started with Run button from QT Creator it works fine.

What I found is that when run on its own application returns error 1 which is **CURLE_UNSUPPORTED_PROTOCOL**

Checking curl on my osx with `curl -V` shows that default curl does not list sftp.

However somehow QT creator runs app in some different context which uses curl that has support for sftp, because it uploads files without error.

So question is how do I make it so standalone application uses the same version of dylib as when ran from QT Creator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**OPTION A) change lib path**

- Find the application running by using `ps ax | grep <appname>`
- Do `otool -L <full-path-of-app>`, this will give you `dylib` your app resolves to
- Change the `dylib` in your binary using [install_name_tool](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/install_name_tool/). [Check this answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33991581/install-name-tool-to-update-a-executable-to-search-for-dylib-in-mac-os-x) to point to `dylib` used by QT creator.

**OPTION B) [un]/set `RPATH`**

Another reason your app is using incorrect path could be `RPATH` on your `dylib`. You can check `RPATH` on your dylib using `otool -l <full-path-of-your-app>`. RPATH tells you the location binary will first pick up libraries from, if it is set in your application you can unset `RPATH` set by QT creator.

Check [man page of dyld](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html) to find out how does `RPATH` work.

For example check `RPATH` set on Xcode app (your are looking for `LC_RPATH` field in dylib section).

```
$ otool -l /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode 
Load command 22
          cmd LC_RPATH
      cmdsize 48
         path @executable_path/../Frameworks (offset 12)
Load command 23
          cmd LC_RPATH
      cmdsize 56
         path @executable_path/../SharedFrameworks (offset 12)
Load command 24
          cmd LC_RPATH
      cmdsize 40
         path @executable_path/../PlugIns (offset 12)
```

To unset `RPATH` use `install_name_tool  -delete_rpath <RPATH-from-otool-l-output>`

QT creator typically uses libraries shipped with its package and on your target system these are typically not present. Better thing to do would be compile `curl` and ship with your application

Comment: Actually still don't know why it was behaving this way, because when inspected application ran by Qt creator was exactly the same I was running by clicking app icon. But pointing to otool and install_name_tool was enough of help so I was able to hack curl into the app that I could deliver. Building statically did not worked because I would have to build curl and its dependencies statically.

Comment: @Mateusz I updated the answer from what I suspect to be your case.